# Str2Func matlab doesnt run the function

Tags: matlab

I am having a problem using `str2func`, when matlab says that the function i called to is
'undefined function 'X' for input or arguments of type 'double'.

There is a string which is stored in `Shape`.
`Shape` gets its string from a function, which gives `Shape` different values randomly.
I have a function for each `shape`, so for example if `Shape` gets the value square, there is also a function named `square`, and i want to call that function according to the string that is stored in `Shape`.

so i wrote this:

```
  f=str2func(shape);
  f(x0,y0);


  function [] = vav(x0,y0)  
    x=[x0 x0+1 x0+1 x0+2 x0+2 x0];
    y=[y0 y0 y0+3 y0+3 y0+4 y0+4];

    patch(x,y,[0.3 0.2 0.45])
  end
```

so shape gets a string 
for example `shape='vav';`
but when i use `f=str2func(shape)`
and i call `f(x0,y0)` it doesn't work.

how can i fix it? and what is wrong with this way?
Thanks!!

More code:

```
draw(shape) 
function[]= draw(shape)
    x0=5;
    y0=20;
    set(myfig,'KeyPressFcn',@keyPressed);


    function [] = keyPressed(~,event)
           switch event.Key

                case 's'
                      y0=moveDown(y0);
                      cla(PlayAx) 
                      f=str2func(shape);
                      f(x0,y0);

                      if y0==0
                      draw(shape)
                      end
```

and the error for example when shape gets the value 'vav' it gets also other value but it works for none of them
Undefined function 'vav' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Comment: Is `vav` defined in the same m-file in which you use `str2func`, or is it a separate function?

Comment: Sounds like your code has a capital `X` somewhere that it should have a lower-case `X`. That's the error message you get when you try to call an undefined function *or* index into an uninitialized variable (the two operations use the same syntax).

Comment: @David 
hello, thank for answering.
Yes both are in the same m.file

Comment: @AndrewJanke
I didnt find a capital letter. i will try adding more code in the main question

Comment: @AndrewJanke
if you spoke about the 'X' i wrote at the second line i meant that it can be any value i have different functions, shape gets a random string and then it should call a function with that name.

Comment: Yeah, that was the `X` I was talking about.

When you say you wrote that example code, do you mean it's all just in one file, as presented?

Comment: @AndrewJanke yes they all were in the same m.file file